# Gradle project refresh failed with empty error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Ok so that's a first..

After upgrading to Android Studio 1.5.1 and updating Gradle (on a Mac).

I'm getting an empty error and it refuses to build.

```
Gradle 'MyTaskTeam' project refresh failed, Error:
```

AS highlighted the "dependencies" part in my build file, so maybe it's a hint?

[image]

Comment: Paste the log please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced a similar error after upgrading to 1.5.1. The problem was caused by my Gradle settings being configured to "Use local gradle distribution". I had to switch to "Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)" in several projects to fix it.

This setting is under `File -> Settings` (Ctrl+Alt+S) under `Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle`

[image: Settings]

Comment: After opening this settings screen, I got an info message, clicked "ok", and the issue was fixed. Didn't find the "Use local grade distribution" option..